# How can I pull after renaming local branch and deleting duplicated remote branch via GitHub?

Tags: git, github, sublimemerge

Everything was in sync with the Remote repository on GitHub.

Then I renamed a local branch in Sublime Merge (right-click → rename branch).

Then I pushed – This did not sync the remote repo, instead I now had two identical branches there, one with the old and one with the new name. So I deleted the old branch via GitHub, because I have no idea how to do it from Sublime Merge.

Now, when I try to pull in Sublime Merge, it says:

> ```
> Ihre Konfiguration gibt an, den Merge mit Referenz 'refs/heads/<old-branch-name>' des Remote-Repositories durchzuführen, aber diese Referenz wurde nicht angefordert.
> ```

English translation via Google Translate:

> ```
> Your configuration says to merge with reference 'refs/heads/<old-branch-name>' of the remote repository, but this reference was not requested.
> ```

What can I do to fix this problem? I guess I have to remove the old branch entry from my configuration, but how and where?

Comment: You need to run a `git fetch --prune` so that your **local** gets rid of the remote branch reference.

Comment: Besides `git fetch --prune` (advisable, but not actually required), what you really must do is *set the upstream* of the local branch, using `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/new-name new-name`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, people. @torek, If you make this an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: use `git branch --set-upstream-to` to fix the *upstream* setting, e.g.:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/bract bract
```

(note that the `origin/` version of the name goes after the equal sign, with no space, in this format; the branch name itself is optional and if you leave it out Git will assume "the current branch name").

#### Longer: how to understand what's going on here

Branch names, in Git, don't actually *matter* very much.  This means you can change them whenever you want.  But there are some issues here, because each Git repository has *its own* (separate) branch names.  Changing the name in one repository doesn't affect the name in another.

Besides *branch* names, Git has other kinds of names, such as *tag names* (often written with a `v`, e.g., `v1.7` or `v2.12.1`) and *remote-tracking names*.<sup>1</sup>  You'll likely be at least acquainted with, and perhaps quite familiar with, names like `origin/main` or `origin/master`, and these are examples of these remote-tracking names.

Whenever you run `git fetch`—including the `git fetch` that `git pull` runs—you are instructing your Git software to, using data from your repository, call up some *other* Git software at some URL.  The URL itself is typically the one that Git saved at the time you ran `git clone` to *create* your Git repository.  Git will have saved that URL under the name `origin`.  This name—`origin`—is actually change-able, but people don't normally change `origin` much if at all.

This short name, usually `origin` here, is just a way of helping you keep track of the fact that there's another Git repository "out there" on the Internet somewhere.  The short name both *stores the URL*, so that you *can* run `git fetch` later without having to remember it yourself, and *forms the basis for remote-tracking names*.

So, when you *do* run `git fetch`—including the `git fetch` that `git pull runs`, and the `git fetch` that `git clone` ran when you made the repository in the first place—your Git software calls up this other Git software, which reads from some existing Git repository.  That Git repository has *its own* branch and tag names.  It may even have remote-tracking and/or other kinds of names.  Your Git software can *see* all of these names—or at least, all the ones they're willing to show you—and the Git hash IDs that go with them.  In fact, there's a command you can use to dump all this out:

```
git ls-remote origin
```

will call up the other Git over at `origin`, have it list out the names it will let you see, and will then just print them all out without actually doing anything useful with them.

But when you run `git fetch`, Git uses this same mechanism to see all their branch and tag names, and uses *that* to *get commits from them* (and to get tags if that's enabled, as it normally is by default).  Then—once your Git has any *new* commits from their set of commits added to your repository—your Git normally *updates* all your *remote-tracking names*.  This involves creating new names, if they show a name that you don't have yet as a remote-tracking name, or updating the existing names, if they show a name that you do have.

What all this means is that if you *clone* a repository that, at the time you clone it, has branches named `main`, `br1`, and `br2`, you'll get, in your own clone:

```
origin/main        (corresponds to their main)
origin/br1         (corresponds to their br1)
origin/br2         (corresponds to their br2)
```

At this point you have *no* branches, which is a really miserable way to work in Git (although it can be done).  So `git clone` now *creates* one of these three branch names in *your* repository, based on the `-b` argument you gave to `git clone`.  If you didn't give a `-b` argument, and most people mostly don't, you get the name that their software recommends, which is typically `main` or `master`.<sup>2</sup>

But now suppose that you use `git push` to delete the name `br1` on the hosting site and replace it instead with the name `anch`.  If you now run `git ls-remote origin`, you'll see the three names `main`, `br2`, and `anch`.  That's what your Git software will see too, so `git fetch origin` will *create* an `anch`, spelling it `origin/anch`.  That's your new remote-tracking name for their `anch`.

What happens to `br1`?  **Nothing.**  It's still there, as a stale left-over.  Your Git software creates or updates appropriate remote-tracking names for the branch names they have *now*, but doesn't clean out the dead ones for names your Git software created earlier, that no longer have any obvious purpose.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git now fairly consistently calls these "remote-tracking branch names", but the word *branch* here is just cluttering things up, in my opinion.  These names *are* "remote-tracking", so that part makes sense.  What they track is some *other* repository's *branch* names, hence the rest of the name—but since they are in *your* repository, and are not actually *branch* names, I think it makes more sense to leave out the word *branch* entirely.  They are names, and they track—as in "follow along with"—a remote's branch names, but they're not *branch* names at all.

<sup>2</sup>To change the recommendation on GitHub, use GitHub's web interface to set the "default branch".  To change it on Bitbucket, use Bitbucket's web interface.  To change it on Google Hosting ... well, they forgot to give you a way to change it!  Oops.  But this is the general idea: you can't do it from within Git, you have to use some add-on.  That's probably a mistake in Git, but given that it's been this way for almost two decades now, it will probably stay this way for a while yet.

---

#### The special properties of a branch name

All the different varieties of names, in Git, hold exactly one (1) hash ID or—more formally—*object ID*, a big ugly string of letters and digits like `c3ff4cec66ec004d884507f5296ca2a323adbbc5`.  This, which is really just a [hexadecimal encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) of a very large number, serves to locate an *object* in Git's "object database", which is one of the two databases that make up the core of a Git repository (the other database being the names-to-IDs database).  It's the combination of these two databases that makes a Git repository work; these two databases, plus a minimal set of ancillary files, are the necessary basic parts of any Git repository.

What makes a *branch* name particularly magic in Git comes in three parts:

1. It's forced to hold only a *commit* hash ID.  No other kind of object is allowed.  (There are three other kinds of objects, and *tag* names, for instance, can hold any of the four kinds.)
2. You can get "on" a branch, using `git checkout` or (since Git 2.23) `git switch`.
3. Branch names support particular settings that other names lack.

It's actually item 2 that's the most crucial here.  Being "on" a branch is how Git keeps track of the *latest* commit.  Whenever you are "on" some branch and make a *new* commit, Git *updates the stored hash ID* to use the new, unique, apparently-random hash ID of the new commit.  Git *needs* the hash ID of a commit, in order to find that commit.  Branch names store the hash ID of the *latest* commit.  Commits themselves store the hash IDs of earlier commits, so by finding the *latest*, Git can find earlier ones.

Given that a branch name will auto-update when you make a *new* commit, this makes branch names work to find *all* the commits.  But since that's not the purpose of this answer / article, we'll stop here without further explanation.  Instead, we'll move on to item 3, the settings.

The settings for any one particular branch name include:

- whether you want this branch name to "merge" or "rebase" with `git pull`, if you choose to use `git pull`; and
- the name of another branch in your repository, or the information needed to locate a remote-tracking name in your repository.<sup>3</sup>

The first item is strictly for `git pull`.  The second item is also used *by* `git pull`, and by `git rebase` and `git merge` as well.

The `git pull` command means:

1. run `git fetch`, then
2. run a second command of my choice, usually `git merge` but sometimes `git rebase`.

Because it runs these back-to-back, it can actually tell a little bit more about what's going on than each command alone would know (which means that you get a vaguely-informative error message, as we'll see).

---

<sup>3</sup>The reason for this funny phrasing is that, for historical reasons, the actual encoding of this "upstream" setting is rather peculiar.  To refer to a branch in your repository, `branch.B1.remote` is set to the literal string `.` (a period) and `branch.B1.merge` is set to `refs/heads/B2`, where *`B1`* and *`B2`* are the two branch names as they appear in your repository.  To refer to a remote-tracking name in your repository, however, these two are set to *`R`* and `refs/heads/B2` where *`R`* is the remote and *`B2`* is the branch name *as seen on the remote*.  These are then run through a mapping determined by the refspec(s) in the *default fetch settings*, which I'm not going to go into for space reasons.  It's crazy-complicated, even though the normal effect is just that, e.g., branch `main` has `origin/main` as its upstream.

---

#### The `git pull` operation

The `git fetch` command needs one or two pieces of information, and the `git merge` or `git rebase` operation also needs one more pieces of information.  In particular, `git fetch` needs to know which *remote* to `git fetch` *from*.  Are we doing `git fetch origin`, or maybe `git fetch rumpelstiltskin` or `git fetch bruce` or...?  Of course it almost always turns out to be `origin` anyway (and that's a fallback default built in to `git fetch`), but it would like to know.

The *second* command, whether it's merge or rebase, needs to know at least one thing.  What it really needs is a hash ID.  It can *take* a name:

```
git merge origin/br2
```

or:

```
git rebase origin/br2
```

for instance both work just fine, providing you have an `origin/br2` of course, but in both cases Git is going to turn that name into a raw hash ID to get its job done.  Git *may* then use the name, e.g., `git merge` will generate a default merge message from the name.  However, if `git pull` is running `git merge`, `git pull` generates its own merge message and overrides this default anyway.

In any case, *both* of these bits of information are encoded into a branch's *upstream* setting.  The upstream of a branch named *`B`* is typically `origin/B`.  That is, if you're on your branch `main`, you made that based on `origin`'s `main` which you call `origin/main`, and you intend your new commits to go *to* their `main` and so on.

That's all fine, and when you create a branch `br1` based on their branch `br1` which you call `origin/br1`, you get a branch `br1` with an upstream setting of `origin/br1`.  You'll see this if you run:

```
git branch -vv
```

(or `git branch --verbose --verbose` if you like the long spellings).  But if you then use `git push` to *change* the name, in the other repository, from `br1` to `anch`, and then run:

```
git fetch
```

your Git will bring over a new name, `anch`, and turn that into `origin/anch`.  If you're thinking ahead, you will also rename your local `br1` to `anch`:

```
git switch br1
git branch -m anch
```

(just before or after renaming the branch over in GitHub or wherever).  But: your branch, now known as `anch`, still says that its *upstream* is `origin/b1`.  You've renamed `b1` locally, and—whether using a web interface or `git push`—you've renamed `b1` over on the hosting site, but the *upstream setting* in your repository is just a specially-formatted string, and **it has not changed**.

Running:

```
git fetch --prune origin
```

tells your Git: *look up `origin`, use that to get the URL, call up that other Git software, inspect the set of branch names, and clean out any old stale names I have*.  That will toss out your stale `origin/b1`.  But your `anch` branch still has the old `origin/br1` as its *upstream* setting.  So now you need:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/anch
```

to set the upstream of the *current branch* (which you now call `anch`) to be your `origin/anch`, which is what you call *their* `anch`.

Without this, `git pull` thinks that it should run `git fetch origin` and then use whatever update got made to `origin/br1`.  Since no update *did* get made, `git pull` complains:

```
Your configuration says to merge with reference
'refs/heads/br1' of the remote repository, but this
reference was not requested.
```

(though actually the English version is a bit different than the reverse translation from the German translation).

Were you to run `git merge` or `git rebase` without supplying additional arguments, you'd get a similar (but somewhat different) complaint, e.g.:

```
fatal: No remote-tracking branch for refs/heads/br1 from origin
```

Note that this requires first cleaning out the "stale" name to get the error.  If we don't run `git fetch --prune` first, there's a "stale" `origin/br1` lying around.  The rebase or merge command will use the hash ID stored *in* that stale name!  The resulting rebase or merge will *probably* do nothing at all, but in general this isn't a great idea.

#### Some slight flaws with `git fetch`

Ideally, it would be nice if `git fetch` would *always* do `--prune`.  You can make it do that:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

This makes `git fetch`, including the one run by `git pull`, automatically do a prune operation whenever it can.  There are some small bug-ettes here, though they are generally pretty safe: if you ever hit a weird corner case, just run `git fetch` again to fix things up, leaving out any extra arguments that caused you to hit the mini-bug.

There are two other things I must mention here:

1. Very old version of Git (pre-1.8.4) often fail to update some remote-tracking name.
2. There are ways to run `git fetch` so that it *can't* update *most* remote-tracking names.

In particular, if you run:

```
git fetch origin main
```

you're telling your own Git that, whatever the list of branch names the other Git spills out for us, we should only *update* **our** `origin/main`.  (The slash here is implied; this goes back to footnote 3 and the [hysterical raisins](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html) mentioned therein.)  When you use this form of `git fetch`, fetch cannot prune (and will not do so even with `fetch.prune` set to `true`).  If your Git version is really old, it won't even update `origin/main`: it will just leave, in `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, just enough information for this old version of Git to finish a `git pull` operation.

Note that when you run `git pull` like this;

```
git pull
```

this runs `git fetch`, not `git fetch origin main`, so these two odd cases don't happen.  But when you run:

```
git pull origin main
```

the `git pull` command passes this entire set of arguments on to `git fetch`, resulting in `git fetch origin main`, so in ancient Git, these two special cases (no pruning and no remote-tracking update) *do* happen, and in modern Git, the one case (no pruning) happens.

The fact that it's this complicated, and that I need to mention this, is a sort of indictment of Git.  I find Git to be very useful and mostly pretty good, but it does have a lot of instances of [meaning 3 here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indictment).

Comment: I once had a software. Whenever I did something dumb, it popped up a dialog: “Being the smart tool that I am, I detected that you want to do <dumb thing>. Do you want me to do <something which fixes dumb thing>?” I loved that tool. Git will never be such a tool. But yeah, Git is a _fascinating_ problem … Whatever, accepted, as promised. And an upvote for the `--verbose --verbose` hint (I just tried `--verboseverbose`). Also for that “hysterical reasons” link. Haha, full agreement.

Answer (score 0):

What I did:

```bash
# Read eftshift0´s and torek´s comments
# Duckduckify "upstream" knowledge, find shorturl.at/tEXY3.
git help                           # too broad
git branch help                    # better

git branch --list                  # OK, renamed branch is active, but too terse
git branch --list --all            # too terse
git branch --list --all --verbose  # too terse
# make console full screen
git branch --list --all -vv        # or `--verbose --verbose`
                                   # OK, better
                                   # lists deleted remote
                                   # blue shows deleted remote
                                   # thats wrong

git fetch --prune                  # eftshift0´s comment
git branch --list --all -vv        # SUCCESS, deleted remote branch not listed

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/new-correct-remote
                                   # torek´s comment
git branch --list --all -vv        # SUCCESS, correct blue remote branch
```

Added to `~/.bash_aliases` for future reference:

```bash
gitlistbranches() {
    git branch --list --all -vv
}

gitsetremote() {
    git fetch --prune
    git branch "--set-upstream-to=origin/$1"
}
```

Comment: The first comment is (was? depends on how long the comments remain) eftshift0's, not mine...